# How to get raw camera data with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, camera, computer-vision, webcam

I would like to understand how to get raw camera data (RGB pixel values) **without** any frameworks like OpenCV, Qt Multimedia or the AV Foundation using C/C++. I can't find any good resource on this topic.

I understand that most of the cameras/webcams have differences, so for simplicities sake what I would like to do is to access the raw input from the iSight camera in my Macbook Pro. (but any kind of camera input is good, USB too)

I assume that there is a port that I can connect to, however I don't really know where to start.

Comment: It's operating system specific. Use a framework, OpenCV is great.

Comment: @iharob I get that but as I mentioned in the description I would like to understand how it works, so I don't want to use a framework.

Comment: There's no portable way to do that, so you'll have to use your OS of choice's facilities. For example on linux you could try reading from /dev/videoX. Or if you have V4L, /dev/v4l/by-id/your-usb-camera

Comment: @tux3 thanks for the linux tip. It is not a problem at all if it's not portable.

Comment: Generally each operating system has it's own mechanism to interact with the low level camera drivers, often the data is in a compressed format, so getting the raw rgb might imply converting the data. In linux you would need `v4l` and some `ioctl`'s, on windows there are various interfaces in the windows API for it, but I have no Idea how it works on OSX, you should read the documentation for OSX multimedia API i guess.

Comment: Why you don't want to use a framework? is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: Here's some V4L doc for Linux : http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/

Comment: At least two of the frameworks you listed are open source.  Go look at the source code.

Comment: @iharob thanks for the brief comment. The reason is simply because I'm doing a research on video streaming and computer vision. I reached a point when I need to understand how things are connected in lower levels in order to continue with my work. I find extremly hard to find organised information on this topic that is why I asked the question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Well as a matter of fact, you should know that sometimes the camera does some data compression and sends compressed frames to the operating system. I have some code that might be interesting for your research, give me your email and i can send it to you.

Comment: @iharob that sounds fantastic, my email is mail@adamhalasz.com

Comment: @Ádám the might be broken, depending on which compiler will you use, it might or might not compile.

Comment: @iharob No problem, the source code alone might give me some insights.

Comment: I'm not sure what step you need.  Generally the OS (Mac OS X for you) will open the USB port when the camera is attached (if it's mass-media mode), so your code will just look in the appropriate folder for your file.  Is your question about finding the file, opening it, or what to do after it's open?

Comment: @NerfHerder In my description I'm actually refering to the iSight camera that is built in to the macbook. However I'm interesting in general about any kind of camera input so an USB Camera sounds good too :) I'm not quite sure what do you mean by the file, shouldn't it be a stream?

Comment: Video will be a stream.  A picture will be a file (which may be called a stream in some documentation, but is a static file in reality).  I was thinking of still pictures, which is relatively simple to read.

Comment: @NerfHerder Áhá! That makes sense. As I'm working on computer vision, my job is about working with image frames from video streams. In these terms I have a difficulty finding the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Try an embedded video board like TI's EVMDM6437.

You cannot go "RAW" without DMAing YUV422 steam directly into CPU's L1!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! By "TI's EVMDM6437" Do you mean this? http://www.spectrumdigital.com/product_info.php?products_id=196 I'm not sure what do you mean by "DMAing YUV422 steam".

Comment: Yes, that's it. That board is a video processing system with composite input and S-video input. A TVP5416 video capture chip converts the PAL/NTSC analogue signal to raw digital stream in 32bit packed YUV 4:2:2 format. The API provided with the board, named BSL(board support library) let you direct such a stream to anywhere in memory, including L1/L2 cache of the on board CPU that can be configured to RAM memories. You can do all the processing you want then stream the results to display devices, like a TV or monitor. This is what I used in college, pretty fun.